# How can I batch rename subdirectories and files in order to replace whitespaces with underscores?

Tags: rename, file-management

I am using Ubuntu and Arch-based OSs and I have tons of files that I have to rename. I have used this so far.

```
    allfiles=$(find ./ -type f -name "*:*")
```

echo $allfiles

```
find ./ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \
```

It has renamed the main folders, but not the subdirectories.

Comment: You are limiting the first `find` to files only, but then you talk about folders and subfolders. What do you want to rename? Folders only? Files only? Both?

Comment: Elysium, what is the purpose of the first find and first echo? How are they related to your question?

Comment: Also, can you give us a directory structure that reproduces the problem? I can't get your command to fail on my system.